# How do I get the scribe to teach me reading in Rattay?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

I just got to Rattay and I can't read.

I found the Scribe behind some locked doors and he was in a bed sleeping. I went to talk to him and he wakes up but I can't talk to him.

I asked around some shopkeepers if there was a Scribe around for me to talk to and they all point to this guy.

Is there something else I need to do before he'll talk to me or teach me to read?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scribe in Rattay won't teach you to read, he is sick or something. If you ask the Bailiff in that town about reading, he'll direct you to a scribe in Uzhitz, in the form of a side quest.

Comment: The Rattay Alchemist can also point you to the Uzhitz Scribe.